# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.oc4j.loader.boot.Oc4jBoot

Tags: database

I received the messge below today when i login on database which is deployed on the linux virtual machine:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/oc4j/loader/boot/Oc4jBoot
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.oc4j.loader.boot.Oc4jBoot
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

I tryed to find the solution but failed, has anyone met the same problem befoe? Thanks for providing a solution or any certification advice.

Comment: The error clearly says `Oc4jBoot` isn't found. Have you checked the ojdbc driver? Can you tell us more about how you are logging into database? I meant client.

Comment: `Oc4jBoot` seems to be missing on the linux machine where Oracle database is hosted. Can you check if the jar file containing `Oc4jBoot` is present?

Comment: @harshavmb   I log on my database with pl/sql developer, when i am trying to log on with name and password, i received the following information:  Initializtion error, SQL*Net not properly installed.  I tryed to config the oracle home again and restart plsql developer, and log with the same name and password, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @harshavmb  I have checked the jar file, the Oc4jBoot is not found.